# Combine two methods. int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, get

If a woman has a partner, erase that partner's partner.
I need to retrieve her partner then make that partner single.
How do I combine `getPartner()` with `erasePartner()`

```
if (w.hasPartner() == true) { 
    w.getPartner().erasePartner();
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    public static final int NOBODY = -1;

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> preferences;
    private List<Integer> oldPreferences;
    private int partner;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        preferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oldPreferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        erasePartner();
    }

    public void erasePartner() {
        partner = NOBODY;
    }

    public boolean hasPartner() {
        return partner != NOBODY;
    }

    public int getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(int partner) {
        this.partner = partner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean hasChoices() {
        return !preferences.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getFirstChoice() {
        return preferences.get(0);
    }

    public void addChoice(int person) {
        preferences.add(person);
        oldPreferences.add(person);
    }

    public List<Integer> getChoices() {
        return preferences;
    }

    public int getPartnerRank() {
        return oldPreferences.indexOf(partner) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tag the language you are using.

Comment: Well.. What is `erasePartner`? Also you don't need `== true`. You can simply have `if(w.hasPartner())`

Comment: There is no need for `getPartner()` here.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have `partner` as an `int`. You cannot call methods on an int since it is a primitive type. However this doesn't make much sense in your context since you are erasing `w`'s partner and not the `partner`'s partner. Instead just call:

```
if (w.hasPartner() == true) { 
    w.erasePartner();
}
```

Also your code doesn't make much sense. Why is the partner an int? Why wouldn't it be a `Person` object. You could change your code to:

```
private Person partner;
```

And

```
public Person getPartner() {
    return partner;
}
```

So that `partner` points to another `Person` object instead of an `int`

Comment: w.erasePartner(); will erase the woman's partner. I need to get her partner and erase that partner's partner.

Comment: the whole class person was provided for me and I can't edit it

Comment: @2cs `partner` is an `int` and does not have a `partner`

Comment: I have methods that set partners like w.setPartner(3); so now I want to retrieve that 3 and erase it which is -1

Comment: @2cs So at the end you want `w.getPartner() == -1`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to get the `Persona` that the `partner` field corresponds to if you want to erase the partner's partner.

Given the code that you have, every `Person` should have a corresponding id that is an `int`, which is the value the `partner` field stores. You'll need some way to store these mappings such as a `Map<Integer, Persona>` that lives outside the `Person` class, and whenever you create a `Person` you have to put it in the map along with its id (which you can generate however you like as long as it's unique).

With this map you can then access the `Person` that corresponds to the partner `int` and erase its partner

```
if (w.hasParter()) {
  Person partner = personMap.get(w.getPartner());
  partner.erasePartner()
}
```

assuming the partner exists in the map (which you may want to check for).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I kinda figured it out. I did it another way. Goes through each person and test's to see if person p is partner with firstChoice then deletes the p's partner. Kinda long way it seems but it works :)

```
for (Person p : list1) {
    if (p.getPartner() == firstChoice) {
    p.erasePartner();
                }
```